# Use a field from atlas layer in aggregate function

Tags: qgis, expression, atlas

I cant find a solution to use the value of the current atlas entity in the *aggregate* function in the *filter* expression part.

Example:

```
aggregate('layer_to_aggregate','count',"field_form_layer_to_aggregate_to_aggregate","field_from_layer_to_aggregate_to_filter"="field_from_atlas_layer")
```

Comment: I'm not sure you can aggregate by atlas layer but, have you tried to set the filter as `filter:= "field_from_atlas_layer"`?

Comment: In my case the layer from which I want the aggregate has to be filtered and the entities that have to be filtered are those which match the value of the atlas current atlas entity: "field_from_layer_to_aggregate_to_filter"="field_from_atlas_layer"`. The problem is the aggregate function don't understand `"field_from_atlas_layer"` to be the atlas layer and I think inside the aggregate function every fields are supposed to be from the `'layer_to_aggregate'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I needed to use the *relation* function of the QGIS project and use the *relation_aggregate* function like that:
`relation_aggregate( 
relation:='relation_name',aggregate:='sum',"child_field_to_aggregate")`

Answer (score 1):

Once you're in the `aggregate()` command it only focuses on the layer you're aggregating, so you can't reference the atlas layer field normally with just double quotes (it thinks that's on the aggregated layer).

To tell it you are talking about a field in the atlas layer (*coverage layer*), try referring to the atlas layer specifically using `@atlas_feature` and `attribute()`. Note that the field is referred to with *single* quotes and is case-sensitive

```
aggregate('layer_to_aggregate','count',"field_from_layer_to_aggregate_to_aggregate",
          "field_from_layer_to_aggregate_to_filter"=
          attribute(@atlas_feature,'field_from_atlas_layer'))
```

Comment: Thank you! Another similar solution is to use `with_variable()`:
`with_variable(
'field_from_atlas_layer',"field_from_atlas_layer",
aggregate('layer_to_aggregate','count',"field_from_layer_to_aggregate_to_aggregate",
"field_from_layer_to_aggregate_to_filter"=@field_from_atlas_layer')
)`